# Inventory Management JAVA ( check if item already exist)

Tags: java, oop, netbeans, inventory, inventory-management

i am making an inventory application using netbeans wherein in the add button, it adds data to the table and checks if the data is already exists in the table.

In my code, it lets me add data in the first row but when i try to add again, it doesn't let me. And it also doesn't check if the item exists in the table when i try to add the same data.

Here is my code:

```
private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:  
        if (nameTF.getText().equals("")||quantityTF.getText().equals("")||priceTF.getText().equals("")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter item!", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } else {
            if(model.getRowCount()<100){

                String item[] = new String[100];
                String product = nameTF.getText();
                int quantity = Integer.parseInt(quantityTF.getText());
                double price = Integer.parseInt(priceTF.getText());
                int x = model.getRowCount();
                boolean itemExist = false;

                item[x] = product + "\t" + quantity + "\t" + price;

                for (int j = 0; j<x; j++) {      //check whether item is in the list already
                    String[] temp = item[j].split("\t");

                    if (temp[0].equals(product)){
                        itemExist = true;             
                    }
                }

                if(itemExist!=true){

                    final int id = ++count;
                    model.insertRow(model.getRowCount(), new Object[]{id,product,quantity,price});
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item Added Successfully!", "Success", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item already exist!", "Check your items", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Inventory Full!", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }

}
```

I can't find the error. Please help me. THANK YOUU IN ADVANCE!

Comment: You are puuting a lot of things in only one method. refactoring the code will be very helpful to the reader. you can for example extract some methods, renaiming the variables name will be also good.